# Display parts of subtitle on different sides with HighCharts

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I have HichChart with subTitle. I want to style it, that one part of this text was on left and another on right side.

I've tried to do this using inline css and turn on `html` for subTitle.

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/h70sj57r/) what I have

```
subtitle: {
    text: '<b>This is</b>&nbsp;<span style="float : right !important;text-align: right !important;">the subtitle</span>',
    floating: true,
    align: 'left',
    x: 100,
    y: 60,
    useHTML : true
}
```

But this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It is not optimal , but you can overwrite the css style like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/k22umypm/)

```
#container .highcharts-container .highcharts-subtitle {
  width:calc(100% + -120px); /*customize this to your needs*/
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I added a right position to the subtitle so that it has a full width, otherwise your float does nothing, the only thing i don't understand is why i have to add the left position with the same value as x so that the "subtitle text" doesn't end up outside the chart.

this what i added

```
style: { "right":"10px", "left": "100px" }
```

if you want more margin to the right, just increase the right property

full fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/h70sj57r/4/

and this is how it look like if i don't add the left position(again i have no ideea what calculations it does so that you need to add this) http://jsfiddle.net/h70sj57r/5/

Comment: It works, but you need to set exporting.allowHTML to true - http://jsfiddle.net/h70sj57r/8/